# Send email using VB, windows 10, stopped working

Tags: windows, vb.net, gmail

I have used VB code to send emails for years. It stopped working apparently due to security restrictions in Gmail.

My Gmail account uses 2-step verification, and I have even generated an "App Password". It still will not work.

My Code:

```
            Dim SmtpServer As New SmtpClient()
            Dim Email As New MailMessage()
            SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = False
            SmtpServer.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password")
```

The "username" is my gmail address, "password" is the "App Password" that I created
The debugger shows no SmtpServer.Credentials.

I have tried many avenues to make this work, short of purchasing software that charges money for a key. I have even tried posted code that was supposed to work.

any suggestion would be welcome.

Changed code:

```
        Dim SmtpServer As New SmtpClient()
        Dim Email As New MailMessage()
        SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = False
        SmtpServer.EnableSsl = True
        Dim MyCredentials = New NetworkCredential("username", "password")
        SmtpServer.Credentials = MyCredentials
```

debug says:
?MyCredentials
{System.Net.NetworkCredential}
Domain: ""
Password: "password"
SecurePassword: {System.Security.SecureString}
UserName: "username"

So MyCredentials works, but
debug says:
?SmtpServer.Credentials
Nothing

I did not show my real username or App Password. What am I missing?

Comment: What error message are you getting after applying the apps password?

Comment: If you have followed the  2-factor auth procedure (created a new App password selecting *Other* from the list, you copied the secure password in yellow background and it's the one you're using here), then set `SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true` and it should be fine -- The `New MailMessage()` object is supposed to contain the `From` and `To` addresses. `From` is the account used when signing the App password

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having is due to the removal of less secure apps, setting in your google account

```
smtpServer.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password")
```

You need to either enable 2fa on your google account and create an apps password and use that in place of your actual password in your code.

Our switch to Xouath2 and authorize the user.

[Quick fix for SMTP username and password not accepted error](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y_u5KIeXiVI)

Comment: This finally worked!! I have two Gmail accounts and somehow the App Password was associated with the wrong account! I have tried to get this working  for 2 weeks! Thanks for all of your help!!

Comment: Remember to accept the answer if it helped you it will also improve your own reputation.